# Understanding Return f(n-1) + 5.

Tags: java, recursion

I am learning recursion need a better explanation of the following code. I have most of it down, but not I am sort of confused on the last part of the function where it says `return f(n-1) + 5`. I got 32 for f(7) which is correct, and that prints out at the very last, but I am still a little fuzzy and was wondering if anyone would give me a better explanation.
The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgAPC.png). 
I know that once n = 1 by `f(n-1)` n being 7 at first, then (7-1) = 6 and so on until it gets to 1, which returns a value of 2, but this where I get sort of lost. What about the `+ 5`? 2 + 5 = 7, 7 + 5 = 12,... 27 + 5 = 32. How does this tie to the `f(n-1) + 5`

```
public class scratch {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f(7));
}

static int f(int n) {

    System.out.println("f(" + n + ")");
    if (n <= 1)
        return 2;
    else
        return f(n - 1) + 5;
}
```

}

Comment: It is not a Factorial method, this is wrong :(

Comment: This is a factorial method: 
`static int f(int n) {
        System.out.println("f(" + n + ")");
        if (n <= 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return f(n - 1) * n;
        }
    }`

Comment: Thank you. I got confused with another problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? When your `n` becomes `1` it returns `2` to `n = 2` and then this `n = 2` returns `2 + 5` to `n = 3` and so on.

For Example, Consider `f(7)`:

```
n = 7, f(6) + 5
n = 6, f(5) + 5
n = 5, f(4) + 5
n = 4, f(3) + 5
n = 3, f(2) + 5
n = 2, f(1) + 5
n = 1, 2
```

As you see, `f(1)` will return `2` to `f(2)` which will return `2 + 5` to `f(3)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If a program says `int x = f(1);`, then it calls the method `f`.  Since the argument is 1, this just returns 2.

If a program says `int x = f(2);`, it calls the method `f`.  The argument is 2, so it executes this line:

```
return f(n - 1) + 5;
```

which calls the method `f` again, with argument 1.  As I noted in the first paragraph, when you call `f` with argument 1, it returns 2, so the above evaluates to

```
return 2 + 5;
```

which is 7.

If a program says `int x = f(3);`, it calls the method `f`.  The argument is 3, so it executes this line:

```
return f(n - 1) + 5;
```

which calls the method `f` again, with argument 2.  As I noted earlier, when you call `f` with argument 1, it returns 7, so the above evaluates to

```
return 7 + 5;
```

which is 12.  And so on.

I think you basically do understand what's going on; hopefully, breaking it down like this will help eliminate whatever doubts you still have.